# How to preserve geometry when saving vector files to a SpatiaLite db (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, vector, spatialite, database, dbmanager

I have been trying to add multiple vector layers to a SpatiaLite database, however using the integrated DB Manager in QGIS 2.14.10 and 2.18.7, whenever I add a shapefile using the "Import Layer/File" button, and follow the menu, the item added does not have geometry, with only the attribute table appearing in the DB.

I can create DBs containing single layers using the "Save as..." right click menu option, but I can't save multiple vector layers into the same DB.

[Other users](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118853/how-to-save-multiple-layers-from-qgis-to-a-spatialite-db) have suggested using the QSpatiaLite plugin, however the plugin doesn't run when installed, and hasn't been updated in 6 years. QspatiaLite seemed like a good answer, if anyone knows of a similar plugin that has been upkept, please let me know.

Here is a snapshot of my SpatiaLite DB, with `GLA_Zips` being the vector file that was added to the original `combined_mix` sqlite file.  Despite checking the `geometry column` option in the import menu, the geometry still isn't imported.  When I click `add to canvas` in the context menu for the item, its added to the layers panel as a table, not a polygon vector file.
[image: DB Manager Screenshot]

The original `combined_mix` layer looks like this in the DB, for comparison, and works in the layers panel just fine. [image: originalSpatialiteFile]

Comment: I can't reproduce with QGIS 2.18.7. I just added three layers to the same existing SpatiaLite db with the DB Manager and all the geometries are there.

Comment: Does the geometry appear after you hit refresh in DB Manager. If not, then try to update QGIS. It is now 2.14.15. May there is a bug in QGIS 2.14.10 that you have.

Comment: I just updated to 2.18.7 in the off chance that was the cause of the issue, and I am still having the same issue.  I added a screenshot so you can see the DB I am working with, and the table that is shown when I add a vector file.
And no, the geometry doesn't appear when I click refresh.

Answer (score 1):

I created a test database with GDAL

```
ogr2ogr -f SQLite -dsco spatialite=yes test.sqlite point.shp
```

I made a connection with DB Manager and imported this same layer with another name.

[image]

Import was successful

[image]

I can see from your screen capture that even your "combined_mix" table does not have a point symbol in the legend like my layers do but I do not know if it means that there is something wrong with the database.